# How to select a value based on a column value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose, **Member** table has a column named **Contact**

If Contact has value , Then Type = 1
Otherwise , Type will be blank

What will be the SQL to retrieve **Contact** and **Type**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`case statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT contact, CASE WHEN contact IS NOT NULL THEN 1 AS type
FROM membertable
```

Comment: `coalesce(contact,1,'')` This is meaningless and wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`IIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function which is introduced and supported after SQL Server 2012.

Syntax:

> IIF (boolean_expression, true_value, false_value)

Use:

```
SELECT concat,  IIF(COALESCE(contact, '') != '', '1', '') AS [type]
FROM Member
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a case in your query to generate the type column.

```
SELECT 
    contact,
    CASE
       WHEN contact IS NOT NULL then 1
       ELSE ''
    END as type
FROM Member
```